# Run fortran routine with multi processor

Tags: multithreading, fortran, multiprocessing, fortran77, intel-fortran

I am new in programming and I am actually a mechanical engineer. For my research I have written a fortran routine for modelling a process.
This routine is quite slow because either has been written by me (and so it's not perfect computationally speaking) and it performs many iteration to reach convergence, so it need time.

But I have a 6 core-CPU and I think if I could exploit all of the cores the routine could run faster than it does now.

The routine is like this:

```
  PROGRAM my routine

  INCLUDE 'dimensions_of_arrays.dim'
  INCLUDE 'subroutines.sub'
  INCLUDE 'subroutines2.sub'

  DECLARATION OF VARIABLES
  ..
  .
  DO LOOP OVER MANY STEPS
  .
  CALL MANY SUBROUTINES
  .
  .
  .
  PERFORM SOME ITERATION
  END LOOP
  .
  WRITE RESULTS
  END
```

In the file of the subroutines 'subroutines.sub' I have more than 20 subroutines, like this:

```
  SUBROUTINE xxx(a,b)

  INCLUDE 'dimensions_of_arrays.dim'

  DECLARATION OF VARIABLES
  COMMON/PATH1/PATH2/G,J,K

  .
  .
  SOME CALCULATION
  .
  END
```

In the file 'dimensions_of_arrays.dim' there are common and parameters used during compilation.

Is it possible in your opinion using multi-processor with this routine? Trying not to modify it "heavily".

I use Intel Composer XE2011 with Visual Studio 2010 as compiler of the code.

Any help is very appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The answer is almost certainly, but it might be a lot of work, and with the detail here we just can't tell. However you are starting from the wrong place. Fortran 77 is dead - please learn Fortran95 or later and try to forget everything you ever knew about common and similar. I say this as the methodology to parallelise this (OpenMP) works much more easily with modern code rather than a standard that was superseded a quarter of a century ago.

Comment: the main problem is that this routine has not been written completely by me but I did important modifications to the original version of the code. Do you think it will takes time to "covert" everything in the new fortran90-95?

Comment: As recommended by @Ian, it would be wise indeed to migrate your code from f77 to f90 at least. Before trying to parallelise your code which is not so easy to do, take advantage of the features of Fortran 90, like modules and interfaces, your code will be purer and more readable. You should also take a look at some compilations options and optimisations flags, that should help a little. Search for "bottlenecks" in your code by profiling it, maybe rewritting some algorithm or portion of your code will improve its speed. Only then you can consider OPENMP/MPI to take benefit from a multicore CPU.

Comment: that cant be right, placing subroutines inside you main program?  In any case this skeleton does not tell anything about wether the code will benefit from parallel processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Intel Fortran, I suggest that your first step should be to add the automatic parallelization option. In Visual Studio on Windows this is project property Fortran > Optimization > Parallelization > Yes. While you're at it, I suggest setting option /QxHost. I don't remember if the old version you're using supports this as a project property - if it does, it would be Fortran > Code Generation > Intel Processor-Specific Optimization > Same as the host processor. Of course, you should be building a Release configuration to enable optimization.

This may give you enough performance boost to be satisfactory. If not the next step I would suggest would be to turn on optimization diagnostics and see what it says about why certain loops could not be parallelized.

You are using a quite-old version of the compiler - newer versions are much better at parallelization and optimization and I'd recommend you use the latest you have access to. If none of this produces the results you want, then I agree you'll need to "get your hands dirty" and add OpenMP directives, but this will require that you have a good understanding of how the program works, which variables should be shared and which private. An intermediate step would be to use the Intel parallelization directives, but these aren't a lot different from OpenMP.

When converting a serial program to parallel, especially an old Fortran code, you have to be very careful when it comes to global variables (COMMONs usually). These can either block parallelization or lead to incorrect results. The Intel Inspector XE tool (part of larger Intel Parallel Studio XE editions) can be good at finding these for you.

Comment: thank you for the exhaustive reply and simple to understand even for me ;)